# How can I accept gzip-compressed content using LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, lwp, content-encoding

I am fetching some pages over the Web using Perl's `LWP::UserAgent` and would like to be as polite as possible. By default, `LWP::UserAgent` does not seamlessly handle compressed content via gzip. Is there an easy way to make it do so, to save everyone some bandwidth?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

LWP has this capability built in, thanks to [`HTTP::Message`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Message). But it's a bit hidden.

First make sure you have [`Compress::Zlib`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Compress::Zlib) installed so you can handle `gzip`. [`HTTP::Message::decodable()`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Message#HTTP::Message::decodable%28%29) will output a list of allowed encodings based on the modules you have installed; in scalar context, this output takes the form a comma-delineated string that you can use with the '`Accept-Encoding`' HTTP header, which [`LWP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP) requires you to add to your [`HTTP::Request`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Request)-s yourself. (On my system, with [`Compress::Zlib`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Compress::Zlib) installed, the list is "`gzip`, `x-gzip`, `deflate`".)

When your [`HTTP::Response`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Response) comes back, be sure to access the content with `$response->decoded_content` instead of `$response->content`.

In [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP::UserAgent), it all comes together like this:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $can_accept = HTTP::Message::decodable;
my $response = $ua->get('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds', 
    'Accept-Encoding' => $can_accept,
);
print $response->decoded_content;
```

This will also decode text to Perl's unicode strings. If you *only* want [`LWP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP) to uncompress the response, and not mess with the text, do like so:

```
print $response->decoded_content(charset => 'none');
```

Comment: From my testing with LWP 6.03 all that was required was to use `decoded_content` rather than `content`.