# Why does HTTP::Response::decoded_content sometimes return undef even when content() returns data?

Tags: perl, encoding, gzip, lwp

I've used LWP capability to handle gzip encoded content as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285305/how-can-i-accept-gzip-compressed-content-using-lwpuseragent/1285328#1285328), but in some cases I randomly get unexpected results at least for the one website I've tested: `$response->decoded_content` could become undefined while `$response->content` still returns original gzip encoded response. Tried even without internal charset decoding (`decoded_content(charset => 'none')`) with the same result.

Comment: Look at Accept-Encoding header - may be you set 'br' as acceptable, but LWP can't decode it.

Comment: @Demiurg This was the culprit in my case, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Is the server perhaps not properly setting Content-Encoding in the response?  In any case, take a look at the headers for both working and non-working responses and look for significant differences.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but when I encounter things like this I look at the source of the module to see what it is doing and debug the code just like any other code. Looking at the `decoded_content` method in `HTTP::Message` shows you exactly what it is expecting. Check that your response has all of the things it expects.