# Why does my REST request return garbage data?

Tags: perl, json, rest, lwp

I am trying to use LWP::Simple to make a GET request to a REST service. Here's the simple code:

```
use LWP::Simple;
$uri = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/tagged/php";
$jsonresponse= get $uri;
print $jsonresponse;
```

On my local machine, running Ubuntu 10.4, and Perl version 5.10.1:

> farhan@farhan-lnx:~$ perl --version
>   This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

I can get the correct response and have it printed on the screen. E.g.:

> farhan@farhan-lnx:~$ head -10 output.txt
>   {
>    "total": 1000,
>    "page": 1,
>    "pagesize": 30,
>    "questions": [
>      {
>        "tags": [
>          "php",
>          "arrays",
>          "coding-style"
>   (... snipped ...)

But on my host's machine to which I SSH into, I get *garbage* printed on the screen for the same exact code. I am assuming it has something to do with the encoding, but the REST service does not return the character set type in the response, so how do I force LWP::Simple to use the correct encoding? Any ideas what may be going on here?

Here's the version of Perl on my host's machine:

> [dredd]$ perl --version
>   This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I happen to have a 64 bit RHEL 5.4 box which has Perl 5.8.8 on it.  I took your code and got the exact same result.  I tried using [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.126/Dumper.pm) to dump the data, but that didn't change anything.  I then went to the command line and did this:

```
 wget -O jsonfile http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/tagged/php
 --2010-05-26 11:42:41--  http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/tagged/php
 Resolving api.stackoverflow.com... 69.59.196.211
 Connecting to api.stackoverflow.com|69.59.196.211|:80... connected.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
 Length: 5430 (5.3K) [application/json]
 Saving to: `jsonfile'
 2010-05-26 11:42:42 (56.9 KB/s) - `jsonfile' saved [5430/5430]
```

When I did this:

```
 file jsonfile
```

I got:

```
jsonfile: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT), max speed
```

So, the JSON data was gzipped by the web server.  I tried this:

```
gzip -dc jsonfile
```

and lo and behold the results are the JSON data as you would expect.

What you can do now is to either use another module to ungzip the data, or [you can check out this other thread which shows how to accept gzip using LWP::UserAgent and handle the request that way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285305/how-can-i-accept-gzip-compressed-content-using-lwpuseragent)

Answer (score 3):

This is [bug 44435](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=44435). Upgrade libwww-perl to version 5.827 or better.

Comment: Cool - thanks for the pointer - but reading Tony's response above, it seems like it's a slightly different issue. Anyway, the version of Perl on the host's system is beyond my reach :(.

Comment: libwwwperl is a Perl module, and there are ways to ensure that you can use CPAN at: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828 but using LWP::Request might just be the easiest.

Comment: Alienfluid, you are mistaken, it's not a different issue. The method `decode_content` which was not used in LWP::Simple before 5.827 deals with both Content-Encoding (here: gzip) and character encoding. I encourage you to install your local copy of up-to-date libraries like Tony said.